regexp with word boundaries not working in TCL
I have following code:
set variable1 "5"
set variable2 "6-7"
if {[regexp {\m\d+\M} $variable1 matchall]} {
  puts "only a number has been provided and that is $matchall"
}
if {[regexp {\m\d+\M} $variable2 matchall]} {
  puts "only a number has been provided and that is $matchall"
}

Basically, i want to only match variable1 which is just a number. variable2 does have a hyphen inside which should not match because i am using the \m and \M which are basically doing the same as \b in normal regex which indicates word boundaries. So when i run the code i get:
only a number has been provided and that is 5
only a number has been provided and that is 6

can anyone give me tip in the right direction? I am stuck with TCL 8.3 and cannot upgrade. But regex should basically work the same way as with never versions.

What's wrong with that result? There's a word boundary between 6 and -, so it matches 6. What result were you expecting instead?

Looks like you want ^\d+$, only digit string. The word boundaries work well, as expected.

I don’t think that is a very good “duplicate” — it bears little resemblance to OP’s problem and is, frankly, full of very poor answers.

In addition to Barmar’s answer, it is worth noting that you do not need a regular expression here. Just test with the string command:
string is integer -strict $s

This permits leading and trailing whitespace, though. If that is significant, you can trim it away with
string trim $s

before using it anywhere. To wit:
if {[string is integer -strict $variable1]} {
    puts "only a number has been provided and that is [string trim $variable1]"
}


I just tested this and it works great. Thanks for presenting this command to me that i did not know existed.

The Tcl/Tk Manual is what you need . All the Tcl and Tk commands are available there to peruse. Tcl is a sweet little language, but it is unique in a number of ways, and takes a little time to get used to. Cheers!

You need to anchor the regexp to make it match the entire string, not a part of the string.
if {[regexp {^\d+$} $variable2 matchall]} {
  puts "only a number has been provided and that is $matchall"
}

There's no need for word boundaries since the ends of the strings are also boundaries.

Thanks for the comment. How did i not think of that obvious solution. i was way too deep into trying to get to work with word boundries. Thanks!
